# Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в решении

Tags: электроника

[image: Расчет цепи постоянного тока]

На изображении схема цепи постоянного тока и параметры. Я составила систему уравнений, получилось следующее:

```
-I1-I1+I4=0,
I3-I4+I5=0,
R1I1-R2I2=E1-E2,
R2I2+R3I3+R4I4=E2+E3,
-R3I3+R5I5=E3.
```

Стала решать по методу Крамера, матрица размерностью 5х6:

```
-1 -1  0  1  0 
 0  0  1 -1  1
 3 -6  0  0  0
 0  6  4  6  0
 0  0 -4  0 12
```

Меня смутило, что определитель можно находить только для квадратных матриц, а у меня получилась прямоугольная. Не могу понять в чем ошибка, ведь у схемы получается всего 4 независимых контура по формуле `p=m-(n-1)` и 2 узла по формуле `(n-1)`.

В чем у меня ошибка, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: "матрица размерностью 5х6:" - ??